# how to handle '\' in json string

Tags: json, escaping, character

In my json message the field which should have one `'\'` comes with `'\\'`

In the below example

```
  "validation": "^[^\\s][a-zA-Z\\(\\) ,.-]+[^\\s]$"
```

Should come as

```
  "validation": "^[^\s][a-zA-Z\(\) ,.-]+[^\s]$",
```

I am not getting why it is happening like this. Any one out there to help me.

```
"getTransactionDataRequirementsResponse": {
    "return": [
         {
             "errorMessage": "Cannot start or end with whitespace",
             "validation": "^[^\\s][a-zA-Z\\(\\) ,.-]+[^\\s]$",
         },
         {
            "errorMessage": "Cannot start or end with whitespace",
             "validation": "^[^\\s][a-zA-Z\\(\\) ,.-]+[^\\s]$",
         },
 }
```

No way I could pass an odd number of backslashes through json. Below is one test code

```
    String jsonString = "{\"validation\" : \" 1\\ 2\\\\ 3\\\\\\ 4\\\\\\\\\ 3\\\" }";                       
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println("validation=" + jsonObject.get("validation"));
```

Output comes as below
validation=" 1 2\ 3\ 4\\"

Answer (score 0):

When you encode data to JSON format all special chars are escapes (e.g. '/' => '//'). And if you want to use JSON data, decodes them using the [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method.

Comment: Just need to clarify I want a value "validation": "^[^\s][a-zA-Z\(\) ,.-]+[^\s]$" in json to be passed to the conusmer of my service. I tried all ways but never could pass a single backslash through the json. I am not a consumer of the service. Always consumer gets no backslash at his side. Need advice/suggestion to get my way through

Comment: Try this: `String jsonString = "{\"validation\" : \"^[^\\\\s][a-zA-Z\\\\(\\\\) ,.-]+[^\\\\s]$\" }";`

Comment: Read this article - [How many backslashes?](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-many-backslashes/198). It should explain how the special characters works.

Comment: Thanks "liding". If I use your string I am getting validation="^[^\\s][a-zA-Z\\(\\) ,.-]+[^\\s]$". Still I am getting 2 backslashes instead of one backslashes as in "validation": "^[^\s][a-zA-Z\(\) ,.-]+[^\s]$", which is the intended output.

Comment: ok, try this `"{\"validation\" : \"^[^\\s][a-zA-Z\\\\(\\\\) ,.-]+[^\\s]$\" }"`. Maybe this will help

Comment: Still no luck. Output is as below validation="^[^s][a-zA-Z\\(\\) ,.-]+[^s]$"

Comment: I have two suggestions:  1. try this - `\"^[^\\\s][a-zA-Z\\(\\) ,.-]+[^\\\s]$\"` =)  2. or rewrite the regular expression - `"^[a-zA-Z() ,.-]+[a-zA-Z(),.-]$"`